# How to redirect form to a url having wild card character in drupal?

Tags: forms

How to redirect form to a url having wild card character in drupal? For example, can I do like this below shown?

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'admin/component/%/edit'
```

or any other alternative approach to do like this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in a form because the redirect has to be definitive. You much know the variable being put into the % via some means.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can be done , but % is not used in this case , % is used when you want to read an element from url not to create a url . to do that you can rewrite your code as follows :

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'admin/component/SOMEVARIABLE/edit';
```

this is an example to get it better , for redirecting to a node edit form we have :

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'node/'.$node->nid.'/edit';
```

so you must find a way to make a proper variable for that.